# How can I handle when I change the screen

Tags: java, swing

I try build the 2 Class: LoginScreen Class and MainScreen Class

When I run program it will show the login screen first then I use username and password to login the Mainscreen are pop-up but the login screen doesn't disappear.I am not sure how to handle it correctly.

Because the method I use is

> public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
>          String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
>
> ```
>    if (OK.equals(cmd)) { //Process the password.
>        char[] input = passwordField.getPassword();
>        if (isPasswordCorrect(input)) {
>            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
>                public void run() {
>                   JFrameExample.main(null);
>                }
>            });
>        } else {
>            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
>                "Invalid password. Try again.",
>                "Error Message",
>                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
>        }
>
>        //Zero out the possible password, for security.
>        Arrays.fill(input, '0');
>
>        passwordField.selectAll();
>        resetFocus();
>    } else { //The user has asked for help.
>        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame,
>            "You can get the password by searching this example's\n"
>          + "source code for the string \"correctPassword\".\n"
>          + "Or look at the section How to Use Password Fields in\n"
>          + "the components section of The Java Tutorial.");
>    }
> ```
>
> }

I know this is the stupid code and wrong way to implement it but can you guide me to make the appropriate one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this method is a method of your first screen, which must be a JDialog or a JFrame. Just call `setVisible(false)` to hide the frame (you may also call `dispose()` if the dialog won't be used anymore).

Also, you shouldn't call the main method on JFrameExample. A main method is normally used to start a new application. Just do what the main method does from your action listener (probably `new JFrameExample().setVisible(true)`).

Finally, an event listener is always invoked in the event dispatch thread (EDT), so there is no point in using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` from an event listener.

To recap, here's how the code should look like:

```
if (isPasswordCorrect(input)) {
    setVisible(false); // or dispose();
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrameExample();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thx you very much but before I can do it I must do 
b.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().setVisible(false);
That's funny for me :D